# Can you import a profile into a maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

A RESTful web service project that I'm working on needs to be deployed to a very unique environment (that requires a lot of custom configuration) in addition to the typical deployment environment and the integration test environment.

I have created a build profile for the unique environment, but the definition is REALLY long, full of Ant Tasks, etc. and I'd like to put it in its own file and import it into the pom.xml just to keep things clean.

Is that possible?

Comment: May be you can show your pom and we can make suggestions to improve that or make it the Maven Way.

Comment: It was possible in older version of Maven but not now I think

Answer (score 2):

The only option with the latest version of Maven at the moment (3.0.5) is to put your profile into a parent POM and inherit from the children.

One day when it is finished, [POM Mixins](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5102) would help but this feature is not yet finished.

Comment: I do agree with the current impossibility, and the proposed solution is definitely a good one. If the things in this proposed profile are though a specialization rather than a generalization, you may want to consider adding it as a child, rather than as a parent.